# JSF updating h:graphicImage

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using poll from primefaces to update an image every n seconds.  I'm flipping between two images right now just to make sure it's working.  Now what I'm trying to do is display images that aren't stored on the server.  I wrote a class that snaps a photo every n seconds.  I don't want to save it to disk to reduce IO.  So I'd like to do something like the following flow

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class myClass implements Serializable {
  public Object getImage() {
    Object newImage = MyClass.takePhoto();
    return newImage;
  }

  public void increment() {
  }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
      <h:form>
        <h:graphicImage value="#{myClass.image}" id="img" cache="false"/>
        <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{myClass.increment}" update="img" />
      </h:form>
    </h:body>
</h:html>
```

So my question is, is it possible to return an Image object to h:graphicImage in a similar way to the pseudo-code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try using the Primefaces StreamedContent class to provide a stream to graphicImage, rather than an object.

Something like:

```
public StreamedContent getImageStream() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(myBufferedImage, "png", os);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "image/png");

}
```

Then in your JSF page:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{myController.imageStream}" cache="false"/>
```

Note that this uses p:graphicImage, rather than h:graphicImage.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!!  One last question, it flickers pretty bad between updates, is there any easy fix to this?

Comment: Flickers in the sense that the web page can't load the images fast enough? You are refreshing the image every second here, how often is a new photo being taken?

Comment: Right now it's every second, but I might move it to 2 or 3 seconds.  I don't need "real time" or I would just open a video stream.

Comment: And fwiw -- even with a 6 second refresh rate it still "flickers" when switching between photos.  Just a quick close/open thing.

Comment: Not sure I can really help with this. I imagine you could write some javascript to overlap images and toggle visibility once they are loaded. Does the issue exist in all browsers?